# RGB to XYZ , image conversion

Tags: c++

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIopi.jpg)
-- original image

[xyz conversion image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YImL6.jpg)
-- xyz conversion image

I wish to convert an image from RGB to XYZ colour space.

Is this code right?

It makes the image darker.

```
for( int i = 0; i <= stripSize * stripMax; i++ )
{
    floatvalue[i] = buffer[i] / 255.0f;
    if( floatvalue[i] <= 0.04045f )
    {
        floatvalue[i] = floatvalue[i] / 12.92f;
    }
    else
    {
        floatvalue[i] = powf( (floatvalue[i] + 0.055) / (1.055), 2.4f );
    }

    floatvalue[i] = floatvalue[i] * 100.0f;
}

for( int i = 0; i <= stripSize * stripMax; i = i + 3 )
{
    conversion_x = 0.4124f * floatvalue[i] + 0.3576f * floatvalue[i + 1] + 0.1805f * floatvalue[i + 2];
    xyz_buffer[i] = conversion_x;

    conversion_y = 0.2126f * floatvalue[i] + 0.7152f * floatvalue[i + 1] + 0.0722f * floatvalue[i + 2];
    xyz_buffer[i + 1] = conversion_y;

    conversion_z = 0.0193f * floatvalue[i] + 0.1192f * floatvalue[i + 1] + 0.9505f * floatvalue[i + 2];
    xyz_buffer[i + 2] = conversion_z;
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? They are different languages so if you are asking about one please don't tag the other. Also you can add an imgur (or any other image sharing platform) link to the screenshot.

Comment: Please format your code properly. But anyway there is too few information in your question.

Comment: If the conversion darkens the image, I think that perhaps answers your question - no it is not right.  Perhaps you intended to ask a different question, like how to correct it?

Comment: How do you know that it darkens the image? Do you display the `xyz_buffer` as RGB colours? If so, no wonder the image is darker: Your RGB components are in the range of 0-255; your XYZ components are more or less in the range of 0-100.

Comment: I am not familiar with the models or the math, but there is a full explanation and a complete implementation in C++ (though not OO so probably easily re-implemented in C)  at http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/rgb-color-space-conversion/.  It is a lot more code that you have, so I am guessing yours is incomplete.

Comment: this code is c++ and image is j2k so can not upload image .... sorry ,,  i see to the rgb viewer.

Comment: and i print the xyz_buffer range is 0-100..  why is it dark?? im so wondering and sorry my language is not english.. image upload success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.. I've used it many times before. I of course modified it slightly so it will convert from a raw buffer to xyz.. It is taken from code I've written here: https://github.com/Brandon-T/CMML/blob/master/src/color.c#L17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>

typedef struct rgb32_t
{
    std::uint8_t r;
    std::uint8_t g;
    std::uint8_t b;
    std::uint8_t a;
} rgb32;

typedef struct xyz_t
{
    float x, y, z;
} xyz;

void rgb_to_xyz(rgb32 *px, xyz *res)
{
    float r = (px->r / 255.0f);
    float g = (px->g / 255.0f);
    float b = (px->b / 255.0f);
    r = (r > 0.04045f) ? pow(((r + 0.055f) / 1.055f), 2.4f) * 100.0f : r / 12.92f;
    g = (g > 0.04045f) ? pow(((g + 0.055f) / 1.055f), 2.4f) * 100.0f : g / 12.92f;
    b = (b > 0.04045f) ? pow(((b + 0.055f) / 1.055f), 2.4f) * 100.0f : b / 12.92f;
    res->x = r * 0.4124f + g * 0.3576f + b * 0.1805f;
    res->y = r * 0.2126f + g * 0.7152f + b * 0.0722f;
    res->z = r * 0.0193f + g * 0.1192f + b * 0.9505f;
}

xyz* convert_to_xyz(std::uint8_t* pixels, std::size_t width, std::size_t height, std::uint16_t bpp = 24)
{
    if (pixels)
    {
        xyz* result = new xyz[width * height];
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i)
        {
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            {
                rgb32 pixel;
                pixel.b = *(pixels++);
                pixel.g = *(pixels++);
                pixel.r = *(pixels++);
                pixel.a = (bpp > 24 ? * (pixels++) : 0xFF);

                rgb_to_xyz(&pixel, result);
                ++result;
            }

            if (bpp == 24)
                pixels += (-width * 3) & 3;
        }
        return result;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;
    int bits_per_pixel = 32;

    std::uint8_t *pixels = nullptr; //replace with correct buffer of pixels..


    xyz* xyz_buffer = convert_to_xyz(pixels, width, height, bits_per_pixel);

    //View the xyz pixels..


    delete[] xyz_buffer;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you Brandon,,, but It's still dark more then original image. I put the calculated values into a RGB array. Dynamically create an array.and put the value and xyz calculated... but it's still. if darkness normal when viewed with the RGB viewer?